# client-server REST APIs security

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cordova, slim

I have a `cordova` client app and I want to restrict access to my REST APIs to only mobile cordova clients, in order to prevent browsers and other not allowed devices to access my APIs.

For the client-side I should do something in `javascript` (the app runs with `cordova`), but I cannot just set a static token in my code and make a `$.ajax()` call to server because users could copy that token, so I need a way to protect the token and the `$.ajax()` call.

How should I proceed?

Thanks

Comment: If the mobile client users have to authenticate, then you can assign each user a public & private key and use HMAC signing for the REST API calls.

Comment: @bassxzero, the authentication is not required in the app.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the server to only reply to certain user-agents. It can be the default Cordova WebKit user-agent, or you could set a customized user-agent for your app in config.xml. Check out `OverrideUserAgent` in the [Cordova documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/config_ref/index.html#Android%20Configuration).

Comment: Yes, a desktop user with some knowledge could find out about your user-agent and change it manually. You could combine this with `device.platform` like Zappescu said, so that it would be harder to gain access, but if restricting access to your backend is so important, you should consider including authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the device [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device) to acquire the platform of the device. I use it for my internal usage stats and it gives you strings like "Android", "iOS" and others, at runtime when the user open the app.
Share the string with your server and you can have what you ask for.

Comment: thanks, but I think that someone could replicate a `ajax` request and passing `Android` as parameter and will get access to server.